Wrong routing in Windows 10
On Windows 10 I have configured the following routing rules:
===========================================================================
Interface List
  9...68 05 ca af 11 9b ......Intel(R) Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter
  3...68 05 ca af 0d b7 ......Intel(R) Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter #2
 13...2c 58 b9 17 8e 93 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (17) I219-LM
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.1.1.2        10.1.1.13     26
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.251.11.1    10.251.11.128     25
         10.1.0.0    255.255.254.0         On-link         10.1.1.13    281
        10.1.1.13  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.1.1.13    281
       10.1.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.1.1.13    281
      10.251.11.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     10.251.11.128    281
    10.251.11.128  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.251.11.128    281
    10.251.11.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.251.11.128    281
      100.100.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.1.1.13    281
      100.100.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.1.1.13    281
    100.100.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.1.1.13    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.11.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.11.200    281
   192.168.11.200  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.11.200    281
   192.168.11.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.11.200    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.11.200    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.1.1.13    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.251.11.128    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.11.200    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.1.1.13    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.251.11.128    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.1.1.2       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  3    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    281 fe80::1e61:1871:3113:995d/128
                                    On-link
 13    281 fe80::ccbe:4503:20e1:8e3e/128
                                    On-link
  3    281 fe80::e67b:f788:1657:7bcb/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  3    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

There are 4 ip addresses configured for 3 network cards.
Let's call them DICOM, AXCS, TACS
DICOM: 10.251.11.128
AXCS:  10.1.1.13, 100.100.0.1
TACS:  192.168.11.200
The cable on the AXCS network port is connected to a managed switch with IP 100.100.0.10 which spawns the 100.100.0.0  network.
From the switch there is cable to the AXCS switch which spawns the 10.1.1.0 network.
Now when pinging form the Windows PC the switch with
ping 100.100.0.10 I get no response.
With a path ping or tracert I see that the IP packets are routed via the DICOM interface which of course cannot work:
pathping 100.100.0.10

Tracing route to 100.100.0.10 over a maximum of 30 hops

  0  xxxx.de [10.251.11.128]
  1  10.251.11.1
  2  10.81.53.155
  3  xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx
 ....

When double checking this with powershell I see that the routing is indeed the same as pathping was showing:
PS C:\Users\xxxx> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress "100.100.0.10" | Select-Object ifIndex,InterfaceAlias,DestinationPrefix,NextHop,RouteMetric -Last 1

ifIndex           : 13
InterfaceAlias    : DICOM
DestinationPrefix : 0.0.0.0/0
NextHop           : 10.251.11.1
RouteMetric       : 0

I compared this with another system with identical hardware and setup where the routing is correct:
PS C:\Users\xxxx> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress "100.100.0.10" | Select-Object ifIndex,InterfaceAlias,DestinationPrefix,NextHop,RouteMetric -Last 1


ifIndex           : 16
InterfaceAlias    : AXCS
DestinationPrefix : 100.100.0.0/24
NextHop           : 0.0.0.0
RouteMetric       : 256

But I cannot figure out what is different here. The routing tables on both systems are identical except that the DICOM Ip addresses on both systems differ.

Meanwhile I could solve the problem by readding the IP Adresse of th AXCS adapter.
After a
ping 100.100.0.10 -l 0 -S 100.100.0.1 

the target IP was reachable. This kept permanently even after a reboot.
